# Turn each line of textarea into a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Let's say for example i have a textarea and a toggle button:

```
<div class="input">
  <textarea id="links">
    http://facebook.com
    http://friendster.com
    http://google.com
    http://facebook.com
    http://friendster.com
  </textarea>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
</div>
```

How do i make it possible for each link in the textarea to clickable with the click of the toggle button?

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
  var clickable = false;
  if(!clickable){
    var links = $(this).closest('.input').find('textarea').val().split('\n');
    $.each(links,function(){
      //lost here
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make clickable links inside textarea, they are for a plain text.

There are possible workarounds though, you can make a div, copy formatted content of textarea to this div, when "Toggle" is clicked, and switch textarea and div.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2zy2/1/)

Your `each` function takes index and value parameters that you can use to make your anchors

```
$.each(links, function (i, val) {
    var newA = $("<a />").text(val).attr("href", $.trim(val));

    $("#links").append(newA).append("<br>");
});
```

(Though obviously you'll have to add them to a div, as the fiddle does.  As anrie says, textareas can only hold text.)